# Unable to compile procedure(oracle) in Symfony 1.2

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, symfony1

- My procedure script :-

  ```
    $person_id='****';
    $branch_code='****';
        $dbh = Propel::getConnection('propel');
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("begin create_retired_employment(:p_person_id,:p_branch_code,:p_error); end;");
    $stmt->bindParam(':p_person_id',    $person_id,     PDO::PARAM_STR, 1000);
    $stmt->bindParam(':p_branch_code',  $branch_code,  PDO::PARAM_STR, 1000);
    $stmt->bindParam(':p_error',     $v_status,     PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 10000);

    $stmt->execute();
  ```
- No error show in log file
- procedure is working fine direct run in pl/sql  :-

  ```
   set serveroutput on;    
   declare v_err_ms varchar2(200);
   begin 
   create_retired_employment(
   '****',
   '****',
   p_error=>v_err_ms);
   dbms_output.put_line('data=>'||v_err_ms);

   end;
    /
  ```
- Please help me what is the wrong in my symfony 1.2 procedure code

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this issue.Third variable is use for if error in procedure but not error in procedure so remove this variable in procedure and then commit.This is working fine.

- This is current script working fine:

  ```
       $person_id="****";
       $branch_code="****";
       $dbh = Propel::getConnection('propel');
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("begin    create_retired_employment(:p_person_id,:p_branch_code); end;");
    $stmt->bindParam(':p_person_id',    $person_id,    PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 1000);
    $stmt->bindParam(':p_branch_code',  $branch_code,  PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 1000);



  $stmt->execute();
  ```